# Issue with 3D PDF created with LaTeX+media9 in mobile app

Tags: pdftex, 3d, media9, movie15

I'm using LaTeX with media9 (MikTeX 2.9) to create 3D PDF.

The resulting PDF document can be displayed in Adobe Acrobat 11 on Windows.

However, I can't load the same PDF in Tech Soft 3D PDF Reader for iOS. The app displays an error message: "Sorry, 3D content could not be loaded from this PDF. The document is either secured or contains no 3D content."

Did anyone else come across this issue and has any clue what might be causing the issue, or even found a solution?

Since the document has 3D content and no security setting, I wonder if it's a bug in the mobile app, an error in the LaTeX source (see below), or maybe a non-standard implementation of 3D annotations tolerated by Acrobat on Windows, but not by this particular mobile app.

(I've chosen this app because it's the one Adobe refer you to; Acrobat for iOS doesn't support 3D content.)

LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9,geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
% text frame on page:
total={190mm,277mm},
% left and top margin:
left=10mm,
top=10mm,
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includemedia[
% width and height of placeholder for 3D object:
width=150mm,
height=150mm,
keepaspectratio,
% lighting:
3Dlights=Headlamp,
activate=pageopen
% filename of 3D file:
]{}{cube.u3d}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

When I run a syntax check on the PDF file (using Preflight in Acrobat Pro), a 'general file format error' is reported. Here's an excerpt from the report:

```
Page 1 from "cube.pdf"
    Problems
        Used profile: "Report PDF syntax issues"
        Document
            Unexpected value for this key
                Unexpected value for this key
            Detailed information
        ...
                General File Format Error
                    An unexpected value is associated with the key
                        **Key: Subtype**
                        **Value: /RichMedia**
                        Type: CosName
                        Formal Representation: Annot
                        Cos ID: 10
                        Traversal Path: ->Pages->Kids->[0]->Annots->[0]
         ...
```

Maybe this is related to the issue?

UPDATE 2:

I tried the old movie15 package instead of media9. This one works, the output can be displayed in the mobile app.

LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,hyperref}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\geometry{
a4paper,
% text frame on page:
total={190mm,277mm},
% left and top margin:
left=10mm,
top=10mm,
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includemovie[
poster,
toolbar,
label=cube
]{150mm}{150mm}{cube.u3d}
\movieref[
3Dviewindex=N
]{cube}{Click here}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To my knowledge none of the Acrobat Readers for mobile platforms supports 3D content. It is a legacy feature with minimal maintenance effort spent on the desktop Reader versions.

Comment: In general, the 3D PDF reader app I mentioned works fine and can display 3D PDF (otherwise it would be useless). It's just the LaTex+media9 generated documents that are handled as if no 3D content was present.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Unfortunately I cannot run tests, as I don't own an Android phone.

Comment: Perhaps the viewer chokes on the play button. Would you please try with option `playbutton=none`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've now added playbutton=none (and removed activate=pageopen to verify the button is gone), but unfortunately it makes no difference for the app.

Comment: Preflight's error report is weird, since `/RichMedia` is the subtype of the (newer) multimedia/3D annotation according [Adobe Supplement to ISO 32000](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf) which documents Adobe extensions to the PDF standard as of Acrobat 9. Interestingly, using Acrobat 10 for manual embedding a 3D file follows the older, pre-Acrobat-9 standard, which defines a `/3D` subtype for annotations. This one is way less flexible then the `/RichMedia` annot. It is weird that Acrobat relies on the old standard.

Comment: Preflight simply doesn't know about `/RichMedia`. If one embeds an SWF file using Acrobat, the `/RichMedia` annot is used. Nevertheless, Preflight reports it as an error, even though the document was entirely produced with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: It seems that Tech Soft 3D PDF Reader doesn't support the `/RichMedia` annotation according to [Adobe Supplement to ISO 32000](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf). Could you please try the `movie15` package for embedding the 3D file? It implements the older `/3D` annotation subtype of the PDF specification.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexG, I really appreciate your help. The output from the media15 package works in the 3D PDF Reader app (see my 2nd update to the original question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tech Soft 3D PDF Reader doesn't support the `/RichMedia` annotation according to [Adobe Supplement to ISO 32000](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf), which is an extension to the PDF standard and on which the `media9` package relies.

The older `movie15` package implements the `/3D` annotation type of pre-Acrobat-9 versions which is less flexible, but which is supported by Tech Soft 3D PDF Reader. Thus, `movie15` could be used to embed 3D content into PDF documents which target this particular viewer for mobile platforms.